# pushing data in each function (rest)

Tags: jquery, arrays

I will try my best to explain what I am trying to accomplish. I have data being returned from my call and on my each function it is in a variable that is getting data from 2 rows of the first 2 items from a list of 30.  How do I traverse to the next 2 items in the list. Do I use push?

```
 $.ajax({                                                   
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            },
            url: "/website/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items",
            success: function(data) {

            var newRows = "";
           $(data.d.results).each(function (index, items) {
   //    alert(newRows);
           if(index < 2 )

           newRows += "<tr><td>" + data.d.results[index].Market + 
              "</td><td>" + data.d.results[index].State + "</td></tr>";
                else
            return false;


});
```

Comment: Can you please show the working demo of this ??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks